# No bounds for the inner summation $\sum_{i=1}^M\sum_{j\neq i}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I have the following. But what does it mean when no bounds are given for the inner summation? Is it a shorthand notation?
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^M\sum_{j\neq i} d^2_{ij}
\end{align}
Suppose $M=3$ I have
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^3
\Bigg ( 
\sum_{j\neq i}d^2_{ij}
\Bigg )
\end{align}
But what are now the bounds of the inner summation?

Answer (score 1):

This clearly depends on context, but I think it is safe to assume

$$
\sum_{i=1}^M\sum_{j=1\\j\not=i}^M d_{ij}^2
$$